# Преобразовать тип столбца в числовой, и удалить ненужные строки

Tags: python, python-2.x, pandas

Есть `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
    Game                    Genre   PvP Rating_Hype
0   4Story                  MMORPG  Yes 7.32
1   8BitMMO                 MMORPG  Yes Req.Votes
2   9Dragons                MMORPG  Yes 7.38
3   A Tale in the Desert    MMORPG  Yes 7.43
4   A3                      MMORPG  Yes 6.50
```

нужно удалить строки в которых в последнем столбце Req.Votes, и преобразовать оставшиеся данные в число, кто поможет неопытному?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [109]: df
Out[109]:
                   Game   Genre  PvP Rating_Hype
0                4Story  MMORPG  Yes        7.32
1               8BitMMO  MMORPG  Yes   Req.Votes
2              9Dragons  MMORPG  Yes        7.38
3  A Tale in the Desert  MMORPG  Yes        7.43
4                    A3  MMORPG  Yes        6.50
```

Решение:

```
In [110]: df.Rating_Hype = pd.to_numeric(df.Rating_Hype, errors='coerse')

In [111]: df
Out[111]:
                   Game   Genre  PvP  Rating_Hype
0                4Story  MMORPG  Yes         7.32
1               8BitMMO  MMORPG  Yes          NaN
2              9Dragons  MMORPG  Yes         7.38
3  A Tale in the Desert  MMORPG  Yes         7.43
4                    A3  MMORPG  Yes         6.50
```

Избавляемся от строк, в которых не удалось преобразовать рейтинг в число:

```
In [112]: df = df[df.Rating_Hype.notnull()]

In [113]: df
Out[113]:
                   Game   Genre  PvP  Rating_Hype
0                4Story  MMORPG  Yes         7.32
2              9Dragons  MMORPG  Yes         7.38
3  A Tale in the Desert  MMORPG  Yes         7.43
4                    A3  MMORPG  Yes         6.50
```

Все тоже самое одной командой:

```
In [117]: df = df.assign(Rating_Hype=pd.to_numeric(df.Rating_Hype, errors='coerse')) \
                 .query("Rating_Hype == Rating_Hype")

In [118]: df
Out[118]:
                   Game   Genre  PvP  Rating_Hype
0                4Story  MMORPG  Yes         7.32
2              9Dragons  MMORPG  Yes         7.38
3  A Tale in the Desert  MMORPG  Yes         7.43
4                    A3  MMORPG  Yes         6.50

In [119]: df.dtypes
Out[119]:
Game            object
Genre           object
PvP             object
Rating_Hype    float64     # <-----------------
dtype: object
```